# To find open set of a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $d$ be a metric on the unit circle $$S=\lbrace(\cos\theta, \sin\theta): 0 \le \theta  < 2\pi\rbrace$$ defined by  $$d(x_{1},x_{2})=|\theta_{1}-\theta_{2}|$$ where

$$\begin{align*}
x_{1}&=(\cos\theta_{1}, \sin\theta_{1})\\
x_{2}&=(\cos\theta_{2}, \sin\theta_{2}).
\end{align*}
$$

**What are the open sets in $S$**?

I know the definition of open sets however I am unable to think of one in this case.

Comment: The main question to ask: For a general metric space with metric $d$, how are open sets defined?

Comment: Side issue: I think $S$ should be defined with $0 \le \theta < 2\pi$ or $0 < \theta \le 2\pi$, else there is ambiguity in the choice of $\theta$ for points such as $(1,0)$.

Comment: There are uncountably many open subsets of the unit circle, so don't expect to list all of them.  A concise description is possible for connected open subsets however.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos he restricts $\theta$ to $[0,2\pi)$ so the representation is unique. We don't get the Euclidean induced topology, because coming from below the $x$-axis we do not converge to $(0,1)$. So the circle behaves more like a line.

Comment: The topology has a base of arcs without endpoints.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I have difficulty in understanding how it is done. @William Elliot

Comment: @SharmiC.  The distance of two points is the arc length between tgem.

Comment: the way you define the metric, you do not seem to identify $0$ and $2\pi$, in fact $2\pi$ is not present, not considered at all, since you say $<2\pi$. So, you are not really looking at the unit circle, but you are looking at the half-open interval $[0,2\pi)$ as a subset of the real line. Think what the open subsets of this interval are, and how they map onto the unit circle.